# Sort in query plan TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization

Need to handle query by eliminating and improving performance by deleting sort operators which consumes the greatest amount of resources.

The temp table is around 20,000 rows and the physical table is around 60 million of rows.

I am using `LAG` function due to that I need to compare values in bigger table, Have You guys any idea to figure it out ?

I am posting query, but if you will need any further info then let me know.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT  
        a.VIN_NUMBER,
        B.CELL_VALUE, B.CELL_VALUE_NEGATIVE_VALUES,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.VIN_NUMBER, B.LOG_NUM, B.SEQUENCE_NUM_OF_CELL 
                           ORDER BY B.VIN_NUMBER, B.DATE_OF_CELL_READ, B.LOG_NUM, B.SEQUENCE_NUM_OF_CELL) ROW_NUM,
        B.CELL_VALUE - LAG(B.CELL_VALUE, 1) OVER (ORDER BY B.VIN_NUMBER, B.DATE_OF_CELL_READ, B.LOG_NUM, B.SEQUENCE_NUM_OF_CELL) CELL_VALUE_NEW 
    FROM 
        #TEMP_CHASSI_LAST_LOAD A
    JOIN 
        DBO.LOGS_FROM_CARS B WITH (NOLOCK) ON B.ROW_CREATION_DATE BETWEEN A.MIN_ROW_CREATION_DATE 
                                           AND A.MAX_ROW_CREATION_DATE 
                                           AND A.VIN_NUMBER = B.VIN_NUMBER
)            
SELECT 
    VIN_NUMBER,
    IIF(CELL_VALUE_NEW < 0, 0, CELL_VALUE_NEW) AS CELL_VALUE_NEW,
    IIF(CELL_VALUE_NEW < 0, CELL_VALUE_NEW, NULL) AS CELL_VALUE_NEGATIVE_VALUES
FROM 
    CTE 
WHERE 
    ROW_NUM > 1 
    AND (CELL_VALUE_NEW <> CELL_VALUE OR CELL_VALUE IS NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Pet peeve: [The semicolon (`;`) is a statement terminator](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-the-semicolon-is-a-statement-terminator/) *not* a "beginningator". It goes at the *end* of **all** your statements, not at the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated. Not terminating your statements properly is deprecated, so you should really try to get into the habit of properly terminating your statements now, so that your code doesn't break if the change is ever forced through.

Comment: Also aliases like `a` is for `Customer` and `b` is for `Account`, or `t1` is for `Purchase` and `t2` is for `Transaction` aren't helpful for you or others that want to read your code. Use meaningful and *consistent* aliases for your objects. I suggest a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: Please share the full query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. Also we need to see what indexes you have already

Comment: I'm *assuming* that's going to be about using semicolons as a beginningator then, @AaronBertrand ? Don't worry, there's already a couple of your blog posts I disagree with; I don't hold it against you. :P

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thing is, no matter whether we agree or disagree about it or other things, at least you're *thinking* and blogging about it. Ultimately, you've made a considered opinion, which I respect. Most people seem to mindlessly push out code without even thinking what it means. See eg `DISTINCT` or `COUNT(NotNullValue)` or `NOLOCK` or `WHERE YEAR(column)`

Comment: @Charlieface I review code with two different pairs of glasses: (1) code that is internal to a personal project or a very small and disciplined team, and (2) code that is for the masses. The latter has to be a little bit safer, in this specific case there isn't even a remote possibility to expect that the rest of the entire audience's collective codebases already have pristine statement termination. :-)

Comment: @Larnu I do mention that `WITH_CTE` or something similar might have been a better choice than overloading `WITH` _again_, but that we ended up in a different parallel universe.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure what you are doing without sample data and full execution plan, but I'd explore a few options.

First, I don't think your `LAG()` is correct. I think you should add `PARTITION BY B.VIN_NUMBER`. Pretty sure you do not want to compare values of different VIN's. This will let you get rid of your `ROW_NUMBER()` as `LAG()` will now have NULL for the first row. That means your `CELL_VALUE_NEW <> CELL_VALUE` will filter out, so can remove `ROW_NUM > 1`

### Optimized Query

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  
        A.VIN_NUMBER,
        B.CELL_VALUE,
        B.CELL_VALUE_NEGATIVE_VALUES,
        B.CELL_VALUE - LAG(B.CELL_VALUE, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY B.VIN_NUMBER ORDER BY B.DATE_OF_CELL_READ, B.LOG_NUM, B.SEQUENCE_NUM_OF_CELL) CELL_VALUE_NEW 
    FROM #TEMP_CHASSI_LAST_LOAD AS A
    INNER JOIN dbo.LOGS_FROM_CARS B WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON B.ROW_CREATION_DATE BETWEEN A.MIN_ROW_CREATION_DATE AND A.MAX_ROW_CREATION_DATE 
        AND A.VIN_NUMBER = B.VIN_NUMBER
)            
SELECT 
    VIN_NUMBER,
    IIF(CELL_VALUE_NEW < 0, 0, CELL_VALUE_NEW) AS CELL_VALUE_NEW,
    IIF(CELL_VALUE_NEW < 0, CELL_VALUE_NEW, NULL) AS CELL_VALUE_NEGATIVE_VALUES
FROM CTE 
WHERE (CELL_VALUE_NEW <> CELL_VALUE OR CELL_VALUE IS NULL)
```

### Things to Review:

- Double check data types for your join conditions. Ex. make sure MIN_ROW_CREATION_DATE and MAX_ROW_CREATION_DATE are the same as ROW_CREATION_DATE. Makes sure it's not text vs date. Ideally VIN_NUMBER is using CHAR(17) (all car VIN's are 17 characters)
- Create index on larger table (and maybe try one on the temp table. Query performance improvement *might* be worth the time to create the index on the temp table)

```
CREATE INDEX ix_test ON dbo.LOGS_FROM_CARS(VIN_NUMBER,ROW_CREATION_DATE) 
    INCLUDE (CELL_VALUE,CELL_VALUE_NEGATIVE_VALUES,DATE_OF_CELL_READ, LOG_NUM, SEQUENCE_NUM_OF_CELL)
```

- Try FORCESEEK option on table join to `LOGS_FROM_CARS`. Be cautious using query hints as can lead to issues down the road, but might be worth it for this query
- Are you sure you need `CELL_VALUE_NEGATIVE_VALUES` from `LOGS_FROM_CARS`? I don't see it used anywhere. Would remove that from the query if you don't need it